# Combine UPDATE with INNER JOIN and STUFF Function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use a stuff query with an UPDATE and INNER JOIN without success.
I need to stuff the results of a query into one column/row and update another table with that result.

My current code is this.

```
Update t1
SET t1.col1 = t2.ordernotes 
FROM db.dbo.table1 t1
INNER JOIN 
    STUFF((
            (Select order_no, Notes As ordernotes
            FROM db.dbo.table2
            GROUP BY order_no
            ORDER BY TimeStamp
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'')
            As t2
ON t2.order_no = t1.order_no
```

The query in the inner join returns the following result

```
Order_no | OrderNotes
1234     | Note 1
1234     | Note 2
1234     | Note 3
```

The desired result is this and then updated into table 1

```
Order_no | OrderNotes
1234     | Note 1, Note 2, Note 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `cross apply`:

```
Update t1
    SET t1.col1 = t2.ordernotes 
    FROM db.dbo.table1 t1 CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t1.Notes
                        FROM db.dbo.table2
                        WHERE t2.order_no = t1.order_no
                        ORDER BY t2.TimeStamp
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                       ), 1, 2, ''
                      ) as ordernotes
         ) t2;
```

However, it is better to get in the habit of using `type` for string concatenation:

```
Update t1
    SET t1.col1 = t2.ordernotes 
    FROM db.dbo.table1 t1 CROSS APPLY
         (SELECT STUFF((SELECT ', ' + t1.Notes
                        FROM db.dbo.table2
                        WHERE t2.order_no = t1.order_no
                        ORDER BY t2.TimeStamp
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                       ).VALUE('.', 'nvarchar(max)'
                              ), 1, 2, ''
                      ) as ordernotes
         ) t2;
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Is it still best to use 'type' even though the column in both tables is already set to nvarchar(max)?

Comment: @DesHutch . . . Yes.  `TYPE` is about extracting the value from XML.  This allows characters such as "<" and ">" to be passed through with no problems.